# Laptop fans run slow and all games lag

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card, fan

My laptop is Samsung np300e5e (series 3) and has intel graphics and I played a game which worked fine but its speakers were not working so I gave it to a laptop repairer.
When I got the laptop back its speaker was working fine but every game started lagging.

### **Problem**

Whenever I played the game (Inversion) laptop expelled much heat out and laptop fan would start running faster and faster and temperature of air coming out of the laptop was too much but now laptop does't go very hot and the air coming out is also not very hot and fan is also not going fast and the game also lags after being repaired.

### **What I have tried..**

I think this is some hardware related issue , I have tried updating drivers and updating the setup settings (F2 to go in setup when booting) and now I am going to install windows again.

### What I want

can someone please help me or guide me what could be that is causing the issue that every game is lagging.I have read much about thermal paste but I don't know if thats the problem.

Comment: I think the laptop repair shop simply change the powersaving settings. Try setting it back to high performance and see if that fixes the issue. It may cause the fans running hot again and introduce the first problem again

Comment: Tried it , did't work.

Comment: its actual shop and everything like ram and hdd and processor seems same and I really think its some hardware issue of the graohic card

Things move slowly Its like lag in every second I cannt say if this is frame per second But Its graphical thing or processor thing with thermal paste

Answer (score 3):

I'd initially check up on the power setting and make sure you're running in High Performance.

Perhaps it may be worth giving the repair shop a call to get a detailed overview of the work carried out on the machine?

Comment: I have set the high performance but still getting lag

Comment: When you mentioned that you were going to re-install Windows, has this already been done or are you still troubleshooting before re-installing?

Comment: I am backing up data and also thinking about trying to do everything before installation so I don't have to do the installation .

Comment: I see what you mean, I'd continue backing up your data with intention to re-install, but phone the repair company in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Thermal paste is like glue to make ur processor cold.

Okay first check task manager.and see if ram/cpu usage is high.show detail and find any process that make ur laptop lagging

Second,try update ur windows.and install all ur driver with driver pack solution

If none  of them working,return that laptop to that laptop repairer and ask him to be responsible